# Python XML or txt find and replace

Tags: python, xml, replace, find

I have an xml file where I want to add some data. I dont want to mess up with the XML tools in python so I modified my input XML file so that I just need to replace some areas in the text.
Here is my script.

```
f1 = open('import.xml', 'r')
f2 = open('output.xml', 'w')
InvoiceNo = raw_input('InvoiceNo: ')
Name = raw_input('Name: ')
Country = raw_input('Country (Bsp.: US): ')
GrossWeight = raw_input('GrossWeight (Bsp.: 0.7): ')
for line in f1:
    f2.replace('<CommercialReferenceNumber></CommercialReferenceNumber>',     '<CommercialReferenceNumber>%s / %s</CommercialReferenceNumber>' % (Name,     InvoiceNo))
    f2.write(line.replace('<DestinationCountry></DestinationCountry>', '<DestinationCountry>%s</DestinationCountry>' % (Country)))
    f2.write(line.replace('<TotalGrossMassMeasure></TotalGrossMassMeasure>', '<TotalGrossMassMeasure>%s</TotalGrossMassMeasure>' % (GrossWeight)))
    f2.write(line.replace('<LocalReferenceNumber></LocalReferenceNumber>', '<LocalReferenceNumber>%s</LocalReferenceNumber>' % (InvoiceNo)))

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

The problem is that if I do it like this I get each line 4 times in the output.xml.

I just want to replace these 4 text phrases but there is no way for me.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Don't use replace with XML. Modifying XML is not that difficult:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = ET.parse('input.xml')
data.find('.//CommercialReferenceNumber').text = '%s / %s' % (Name, InvoiceNo)
data.find('.//DestinationCountry').text = Country
data.find('.//TotalGrossMassMeasure').text = GrossWeight
data.find('.//LocalReferenceNumber').text = InvoiceNo
data.write('output.xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in f1:

    f2.replace('<CommercialReferenceNumber></CommercialReferenceNumber>',     '<CommercialReferenceNumber>%s / %s</CommercialReferenceNumber>' % (Name,     InvoiceNo))
    line = line.replace('<DestinationCountry></DestinationCountry>', '<DestinationCountry>%s</DestinationCountry>' % (Country))
    line = line.replace('<TotalGrossMassMeasure></TotalGrossMassMeasure>', '<TotalGrossMassMeasure>%s</TotalGrossMassMeasure>' % (GrossWeight))        
    line = line.replace('<LocalReferenceNumber></LocalReferenceNumber>', '<LocalReferenceNumber>%s</LocalReferenceNumber>' % (InvoiceNo))        


    f2.write(line)
```

Comment: "f2.replace" looks strange, maybe you need do it using line variable

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
f1 = open('import.xml', 'r')
f2 = open('output.xml', 'w')
InvoiceNo = raw_input('InvoiceNo: ')
Name = raw_input('Name: ')
Country = raw_input('Country (Bsp.: US): ')
GrossWeight = raw_input('GrossWeight (Bsp.: 0.7): ')
data = f1.read()  # read whole file

data = data.replace('<CommercialReferenceNumber></CommercialReferenceNumber>',     '<CommercialReferenceNumber>%s / %s</CommercialReferenceNumber>' % (Name,     InvoiceNo))
data = data.replace('<DestinationCountry></DestinationCountry>', '<DestinationCountry>%s</DestinationCountry>' % (Country)))
data = data.replace('<TotalGrossMassMeasure></TotalGrossMassMeasure>', '<TotalGrossMassMeasure>%s</TotalGrossMassMeasure>' % (GrossWeight)))
data = data.replace('<LocalReferenceNumber></LocalReferenceNumber>', '<LocalReferenceNumber>%s</LocalReferenceNumber>' % (InvoiceNo)))

f2.write(data)

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

*It's cleaner and more sophisticated if you use **[The ElementTree XML API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)**, but if you want to avoid this, I will suggest the following:*

**template.xml:**

```xml
<CommercialReferenceNumber>{name} / {invoice}</CommercialReferenceNumber>
<DestinationCountry>{country}</DestinationCountry>
<TotalGrossMassMeasure>{gross_weight}</TotalGrossMassMeasure>
<LocalReferenceNumber>{invoice}</LocalReferenceNumber>
```

**script.py**:

```py
invoice_no = raw_input('InvoiceNo: ')
name = raw_input('Name: ')
country = raw_input('Country (Bsp.: US): ')
gross_weight = raw_input('GrossWeight (Bsp.: 0.7): ')


with open('template.xml', 'r') as xml_template:
    with open('output.xml', 'w') as result:
        xml_data = xml_template.read()
        result.write(xml_data.format(
            name=name,
            country=country,
            gross_weight=gross_weight,
            invoice=invoice_no
            ))
```

***NB:*** python variables are lowercase_underscore_separated variables. Check [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to be able to write more pythonic code.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your code, we can see that you writing 3 more lines for each line that you are reading from f1...

You program thinks this way:

> For each line in f1, I'll create 1 line in f2 replacing the
> `CommercialReferenceNumber`. Then i wont stop!! I'll write 1 more line with the `DestinationCountry` replacement, 1 more line with the `TotalGrossMassMeasure` and 1 more line for the `LocalReferenceNumber`.
>
> So, for each line in my f1 file, i'll write 4 lines into f2 output file.

Instead, you can try using this piece of code:

```
for line in f1:
    line = line.replace('<CommercialReferenceNumber></CommercialReferenceNumber>',     '<CommercialReferenceNumber>%s / %s</CommercialReferenceNumber>' % (Name,     InvoiceNo))
    line = line.replace('<DestinationCountry></DestinationCountry>', '<DestinationCountry>%s</DestinationCountry>' % (Country))
    line = line.replace('<TotalGrossMassMeasure></TotalGrossMassMeasure>', '<TotalGrossMassMeasure>%s</TotalGrossMassMeasure>' % (GrossWeight))
    line = line.replace('<LocalReferenceNumber></LocalReferenceNumber>', '<LocalReferenceNumber>%s</LocalReferenceNumber>' % (InvoiceNo))
    
    f2.write(line)
```

For each line that I read from f1, I'll write only 1 time into f2.

If your line don't meet the requirements, then nothing will happen to the current line.

Ex.:

```
a = "ABC"

print a.replace("A", "test")
print a.replace("D", "test")

>>> testBC
>>> ABC
```